# pass through query in access vba time out happens due to inactivity? or regardless of activity?

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2010, ms-access-2007, ms-access-2013, ms-access-2003

Im working with MS Access and using Sql Server as back end im using Passthrough queries and set the ODBC Connection Timeout property. I want to know the time out error happens due to inactivity on the datasheet view of the particular query or regardless of what someone is doing on the datasheet view

Comment: Perhaps you can be more specific about what actually happens?

Comment: i got the ODBC call failed,Timeout error after 60 seconds i want to know whether it happens due to idleness of that particular page or it'll happen irrespective of what someone is doing on that particular page?